# Does removeFromParent on SKNode destroy the instance?

Tags: ios, ios7, sprite-kit

Reading Apple's documentation about removeFromParent it says:

"Removes the receiving node from its parent."

Does this mean the node is destroyed? Do I need to set the node to NULL for its memory to be freed?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

An object (under ARC) is released when there is no strong reference holding on to it. A node being a child is a strong reference, removing the node will usually release the node unless there is a strong reference to it elsewhere.

You can easily verify this by implementing `-(void) dealloc` and setting a breakpoint or `NSLog` statement in it.